# Change ant design collapse content and header text color

Tags: reactjs, antd

How do I change the text color of the header and also for the content which is `ant-collapse-content`. I'm styling the `AntCollapse` using `Styled` and here's my code:

```js
const StyledCollapse = styled(AntCollapse)`
  &&& {
    border: none;
    border-radius: 0px;
    box-shadow: none;  
    background: #0e0304;
  }
  .ant-collapse-content {
    fontSize: 25px;
    color: #fff;
  }
  .ant-collapse-header {
    fontSize: 25px;
    color: #fff;
  }
`;
```

I tried using **:global** for both `content` and `header` but it didnt work as well.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
const StyledCollapse = styled(AntCollapse)`
  &&& {
    border: none;
    border-radius: 0px;
    box-shadow: none;  
    background: #0e0304;
  }
  &.ant-collapse-content {
    fontSize: 25px;
    color: #fff;
  }
  &.ant-collapse-header {
    fontSize: 25px;
    color: #fff;
  }
`;
```

Comment: I moved `ant-collapse-content` upwards and the problem is now solved. Thank you for your help though! :D